# How to find the path of the feed for content type in drupal 7?

Tags: feeds

I wanted to add the path to the feed view display, but I'm not able to know what the path is?

Comment: What kind of feed is it, and which module created it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to create feeds. Simply add a new display of type "Feed" and customize the view to contain only the content you want. **You have to set the path** in Feed Settings(enter your own path for example: type feed or any path you want).

To add a "Feed" display:

Go to your views administration and select the view you want to edit. Towards the top of the page you will see the "Displays" heading with an "+ Add" button. Click that and select "Feed" . You will then have a Feed display that is using the Default Display's settings.